# Microsoft Graph API, Region is required when request with application permission

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to access Microsoft Graph API to search the list items present in tenant. I am having no problem when GET request is executed for users or groups.

When I post the request for search using HttpClient as described on MS site. I am getting below error.

Failed to call the web API: BadRequest
Content: {"error":{"code":"System.Exception","message":"SearchRequest Invalid (Region is required when request with application permission.)\r\nRegion is required when request with application permission.","target":"","details":null,"warnings":null,"level":"Error","httpCode":400},"Instrumentation":{"TraceId":null}}

I tried with .Net core as well. same error.
If i paste access code on HTML file, calling api for search using Ajax is working fine.

what code i am missing in my c# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason should be this endpoint you use not support application permission.

Usually this error message is encountered, indicating that application permission is not supported, you can use delegated permissions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/927053/index.html
not supported

Answer (score 1):

Although as @json-pan answered its possible application permission is not supported, that was not the experience I had. I simply added the region to my request and it works:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem",
                "site"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "git"
            },
            "region": "US"
        }
    ]
}
```